# JQuery Data table Script error in IE 11 for +45 columns

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using JQuery Datatable to construct the table. The table has 45+ Columns.
The number of rows that can be viewed in the table is maximum of 50 records. The pagination and sorting are achieved in the backend (Not using inbuilt functionalities of the pagination and sort).

The table is constructing properly in Chrome and Mozilla but in IE Edge the script error is coming saying '***the script execution taking too long***'.

Is there a way to improve the efficiency?

Comment: Can you post the associated Javascript, HTML and JSON?

Comment: Preparing mock implementation, I cannot post actual implementation.